# difficult to select radio buttons on iPhone/mobile website

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, mobile, user-experience

On my mobile website I have a `Yes` or `No` radio button question at a critical stage of the site.

I have received an odd report to say that on occasion these radio buttons can be difficult to select on touch-enabled devices such the iPhone.

Interestingly, I have seen it for myself where a user stabbed away around the radio buttons and *eventually* it highlights as being selected. Then I took the handset myself and was able to highlight it immediately.

Can there be an issue with touch technique? (if there is such a thing). I've read about some iPhones that have issues with the touch screen sensitivity, however if I am able to highlight it then does that rule out an issue with the phone.

What i'd like to have is an area around the radio button itself and the label so that if a user touches either then the radio button would be selected. Is this possible?

This is my current markup:

```
<input type="radio" name="del_standard_use_b_as_s" id="del_standard_use_b_as_s_yes" value="yes">
<label for="del_standard_use_b_as_s_yes" class="use_existing">Yes</label>
```

This is a screen-grab of how the radio buttons display on a mobile.

[image: Yes/No radio buttons]

Comment: Are you using a library like Fastclick?

Comment: @Pointy No, is that worth investigating? Is there any overhead? As you can see the radio buttons have an image background.

Comment: Well what [Fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) does is accelerate a "click" from touch events. Browsers translate touch events to click, but they're really slow about it. If you know that your site doesn't care about fancy touch gestures, and that you just want clicks, then Fastclick helps with that. However, it's quite complicated, and sometimes it introduces problems like what you describe. There are ways to tweak it however. If you're not using the library, then the point is moot :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the label around the input and add some padding to the label.